# Is it possible to specify a unique name to terminal windows to run the command via python?

Tags: command-line, python

I have to run terminal codes via `os.system()` in Python. Two commands should be run in two terminals separately. Is it possible to specify a unique name/ID to the terminal windows to run each command in its specified terminal window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each terminal you open gets a uniquely numbered file (a pseudoterminal slave (PTS) device to be exact) in `/dev/pts/` with whom it can be recognized and addressed. To get the correspondent filename of a terminal window you can use e.g. `tty` (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1007110/507051) for alternatives; read `man pts` for more):

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/4
```

You can use this filename for instance to redirect output to a different terminal window like so:

```bsh
$ echo test >/dev/pts/4  # run anywhere
test                     # printed in terminal window 4
```

You can't really run a command in another terminal, simply because it's not the terminal that runs a command, but rather the shell which normally runs in a terminal. You can however emulate the behaviour of a command run in a terminal window with redirections as follows (taken from [Linux pseudo-terminals: executing string sent from one terminal in another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8677623/6164712)):

```
echo test </dev/pts/4 &>/dev/pts/4
```

If you want to display the command you ran as well I recommand writing a function ([How do I use $* while omitting certain input variables like $1 and $2 in bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1011660/507051)), e.g.:

```bsh
run_in(){
  t=/dev/pts/$1 &&
  echo "${*:2}" >$t &&
  eval "${@:2}" <$t &>$t
}
```

In one line:

```bsh
run_in(){ t=/dev/pts/$1&&echo "${*:2}" >$t&&eval "${@:2}" <$t &>$t;}
```

Use it like so:

```bsh
$ run_in 4 echo test  # run anywhere
$ echo test           # printed in terminal window 4 (if prompt was already there)
test                  # printed in terminal window 4
```

In this scenario the only unknown are the `/dev/pts/?` numbers that your Python program shall use. One possible way to get these numbers is to launch your own terminal windows, which will output their 'numbers' in to a file, then you can read it <sup>[[ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/967720/566421)]</sup>. Let's assume you are using `gnome-terminal`, the relevant part of the Python code could be something as follow <sup>[[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760215/6543935)]</sup>:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess

os.system("gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'tty > /tmp/my-app-tty-1; exec bash'")
my_terminal_1 = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "/tmp/my-app-tty-1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
command = "echo Test on: $(date) >" + my_terminal_1
print my_terminal_1
print command
os.system(command)
```

If it is a Perl script <sup>[[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200810/6543935)]</sup>

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/perl
os.system("gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'tty > /tmp/my-app-tty-1; exec bash'");
my $my_terminal_1 = `cat /tmp/my-app-tty-1`;
my $command = "echo Test on: \$\(date\) > $my_terminal_1";
print ("$my_terminal_1");
print ("$command");
os.system("$command");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Itried to run this command `os.system("echo "+stopDBCommand+" >/dev/pts/20")`  in which `stopDBCommand=/home/esarah/workspace/vt -stop /home/esara/workspace/home/mydb` , it prints the command on terminal, but not running it,  i should press enter to run it. It is not running the command, but it randomly ran the command once. how to solve this?

Comment: @sc241 Did you read my whole post yet? I explained this and provided a solution in the second part of my answer…

Comment: Appendix: (1) The python program can execute `gnome-terminal --working-directory='/home/<user>/project' -x bash -c "tty > /tmp/my-app-tty-1; exec bash"` to open a new terminal... then we can read the file `/tmp/my-app-tty-1` to get the `pts` number ([reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/967720/566421)); (2) We can use `tmux` (or `screen`)  instead of a terminal ([reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/962820/566421)).

Comment: @pa4080 I am very new in terminal command , it is very difficult to understand  it. Could you please write an answer?

Comment: dessert, thanks for help, where should I write `run_in()` function? I am very new in ubuntu and terminal commands

Comment: @pa4080 I would really appreciate it if you could write it here

Comment: @sc241, done, please review the answer.

Comment: @pa4080 what is `#!/usr/bin/perl`? where should I write this codes? Or I do not understand where should i write `run_in` function. could you please explain it?

Comment: @sc241, `#!/usr/bin/perl` is [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). The code that I added is a working example of a Perl script  (sorry for the ugly example, this is my first attempt with Perl). Place the lines in to a file (let's call it `file.pl`), make it executable (`chmod +x file.pl`), and execute it (`./file.pl`) to see the result. `run_in()` is a bash function, you can place it in your `~/.bashrc` file, then execute `source ~/.bashrc` and it will be accessible as shell command. Better idea is to create your own Perl function on its base.

Comment: @pa4080 Thanks for your help, I added the `run_in()` function to `~/.bashrc`, however, once I am sending the command `os.system("run_in 2 "+queryCommand)`, where the `queryCommand=./vt -query ./home/mydb ./home/images/image-001-053.png 2>&1 | tee ./
results.txt` . I am getting this error `sh: 1: run_in: not found`, am I doing mistakes?