# How to force bash terminal to run Enter after recieving command via python os.system()?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, python-2.7

I am running some bash commands via python `os.system('/vt -start ./home/mydb ./home/images/image-001-053.png 2>&1 | tee ./ results.txt >/dev/pts/2')`. 
This is a command which can be run on terminal with `tty=/dev/pts/2`.

After running the command , the output of bash terminal is saved in a file (`results.txt`) and later I should read the file. The problem is that after running the command, I need to press keyboard `Enter key` manually to run the next command in the same terminal with `tty` number `2`, python is not forcing `'\n'` to return to command line again.

Do you have any suggestion? How can I add a command which simulates keyboard `Enter key` on the terminal?

Comment: What is the specific command? Generally, you can either tell the program not to prompt for input, or you can pipe your input directly into the command. So if your command was `read` (which requires you to press enter), then you could do `echo | read` from bash to get around that. `expect` is a more advanced tool for this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can solve this without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you try to give one?

Comment: Whatever it should do, don't use os.system() anymore. Deprecated and terribly, terribly outdated.

Comment: @Harry this is my command `./vt -start ./home/mydb ./home/images/image-001-053.png 2>&1 | tee ./
results.txt >/dev/pts/2`

Comment: @JacobVlijm What should I use instead? I need to run the command via bash terminal (which is two different bash terminals), one is `>/dev/pts/2` and the other `>/dev/pts/18`.  One acts as client side

Comment: @sc241 depends on the situation, I can't see what the python code should do exactly, but most likely either `subprocess.call()`, `subprocess.Popen()` or `subprocess.check_output()`.

Comment: @sc241 Can you edit your question to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I want to help but I can't until I have that here.

Comment: @Harry, sorry i am new here, sure. i will try

Comment: @JacobVlijm OP's situation is explained [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1023401/507051) – you're welcome to change or extend my answer there!